# What are the benefits of this? The structure is declared in the header file, and is defined in the original file as follows

Tags: c

What are the benefits of this? The structure is declared in the header file, and is defined in the original file as follows:

a.h

```
struct A;  //declared in the header
struct B{
    struct A *a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

a.c

```
//defined in the original file
struct A{
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

Comment: The member `a` in `struct B` is an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). The `struct A` itself is an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) when seen from `"a.h"` or files that `#include "a.h"`.

Comment: The purpose it to not reveal internal details of the struct to any client using the header.

Comment: to  Gerhardh:  your answer does make sense, any other benefits?

Comment: to pmg : THANKS!!!! I've never known the word to describe this. NOW I now its called opaque pointer. the word in  wikipedia helps me a lot

Comment: You can also use it in case you have 2 structs that contain pointers to each other. You must use an opaque pointer in one of them to break the circular dependency.